# WSO2 EI cache mediator, how to validate control headers

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I was working on the ESB inside the cache mediator and I was wondering how to use enableCacheControl Headers and what kind of headers I can pass through inside my sequence.

es. cacheMediator    " enableCacheControl  true  enableCacheControl "

es. headerMediator   "header name="Cache-Control" scope="transport" value="no-cache"  "

Using this kind of headers inside my sequence I was thinking it would be fixed the question but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It should be looking for this header "Cache-Control" and control the cache according to it. Sample value for the Cache-Control header would be "no-cache, max-age=60"

Comment: i tried different headers but i didn't get my goal.

es.     header name="Cache-Control" scope="transport" value="no-cache"/
          header name="Cache-Control" scope="transport" value="max-age = 60"/